# angular-ui-tree complex to use in project . need guidance

Tags: angularjs, github, angularjs-directive, treeview, angular-ui-tree

i try to use angular-ui-treeview library in my project available on below mentioned link :
https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree

on this , in readme.md , 
in Usage section following things mentioned ;
Download
1.) Using bower to install it. **bower install angular-ui-tree**
2.) **Download from github**.

bower install angular-ui-tree exactly do what and if i need to download all the code from github and need to inject in my project then why i need to install angular-ui-tree
i am new to angular and github as well 
Please provide guidance to use this treeview in project

Comment: @olesia : hi , you have used the same library .share steps to use thisd

Comment: you can see https://github.com/gaurishanker/angular-ui-tree as your starting point

Answer (score 0):

what they're trying to say is that first you must install **angular-ui-treeview** and once it has been installed to your proyect they suggest you to download the example code for you to learn to implement it. All you have to do if you want to learn first is download the code from github and then run it in your machine and get along with it. And when you feel prepared you should install it in your project using bower.

Let me know if helps.